# Monitor blocking queries in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, blocking, activity-monitor

I have to monitor blocking queries in SQL Server 2012.  How do we figure out which queries are the locked ones? Do I use the Activity Monitor? I want actual SQL statements.

Comment: This question belongs to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Okay will post it there.

Answer (score 0):

Run sp_who2.

You can scrol down the results looking at the BlkBy column. Any SPID that has a number is blocked by the spid in the Blkby column. It's actually possible to trace these back until you get to the original blocker SPID.